# Any performance impact or reason to delete unused views?

Tags: 7, views

I have maybe 250 views on a site build and estimate that I use around 150 of them.

Is it ok to leave the extras there unused? It would take days trying to guarantee views aren't being used in custom blocks and in hooks for other views.

Comment: `250 views` SAY WHAT??? I'd like to know how you got to 250/150 views? Do you not use contextual filters? Are you creating a new view for each node/user/taxonomy or what? lol

Comment: I know I know.. It's just an extremely complex LMS years in the making. My Views answers on here show I'm more than competent with Views :P I'm just wondering if it's a performance hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are never loaded/rendered, there should be no performance hit, except for the admin viewing the `/admin/structure/views` page since they get listed there.

Ok, maybe a slight performance hit, since the view table ID's in your DB is bigger, so it would take longer to find an ID, but if you're caching your Views you will be fine.

Comment: Ok, I guess it's definitely not worth it to try and find what's unused. Thanks.